# Using mailgun message builder to send bulk email to individual recipients

Tags: php, php-7, mailgun

I am using mailgun as an API service in php to send emails. However i am building a module in which i can send email to my subscribers.

I'm using the below code to achieve the same.

```
$builder = new MessageBuilder();
$builder->setFromAddress("updates@somedomain.com", array("first"=>"Some Domain"));
foreach ($subscribers as $key => $value)
    $builder->addToRecipient($value['email']);

$builder->setSubject($subject);
$builder->setHtmlBody(include("email-templates/emailSubscribers.php"));
if(strlen($attachment) > 20)
    $builder->addAttachment($attachment); 

try
    {
        $mgClient = Mailgun::create(MAILGUN_API_KEY);
        $result = $mgClient->messages()->send(MAILGUN_DOMAIN_NAME, $builder->getMessage());

        if(strpos($result->getMessage(), 'Queued') !== false)
            return  [ 'status' => true ];
        else
            return  [ 'status' => false, 'message' => $result->getMessage() ];
        // For the ID: $response->getId()
    }
catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        echo json_encode(
                            [
                                'type' => 'error',
                                'heading' => 'Could not broadcast!',
                                'message' => 'Some problem occurred while sending emails, kindly debug. '.$e
                            ]
                        );
    }
```

The code works absolutely fine, only hiccup is that when the mail is sent all the recipients are marked in `TO` and anyone can see the mails in `TO` i want to make it look like the mail is sent to every subscriber as an individual and also it should not be marked as spam by the mail servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Sending as batch message

```
$mgClient = Mailgun::create(MAILGUN_API_KEY);
$builder= $mgClient->messages()->getBatchMessage("somedomain.com");

//regular stuff
$builder->setFromAddress("updates@somedomain.com", array("first"=>"Some Domain"));
foreach ($subscribers as $key => $value)
    $builder->addToRecipient($value['email']);

$builder->setSubject($subject);
$builder->setHtmlBody(include("email-templates/emailSubscribers.php"));
if(strlen($attachment) > 20)
    $builder->addAttachment($attachment); 

$builder->finalize(); //equivalent of ->send
```

Comment: how should i run this in try catch block? which part should i put in try catch block to catch exceptions?

Comment: Also how to track the response to check if the messages was queued / sent

Comment: `finalize()` will go in try catch and batch sending won't return any tracking info also note that batch sending fails if recipients are above 1k

Comment: So if i'm getting no response, how should i assume that the message is queued? Also, what if i have emails more than 1k? How should i achieve logic for that?

Comment: Your above solution provided works as charm as i wanted, it should be marked as expected answer